# Como ingresar numeros en las posiciones pares e impares de un arreglo?

Tags: python, array, funciones

Hola tengo una duda con respecto a un ejercicio de funciones y arreglo en python, este es ingresar por teclado 12 numeros y guardar en las posiciones parea los numeros pares y en las posiciones impares los numeros impares.

Inicialmente se me dio este codigo para la realizacion del ejercicio sin embargo no funciona:

def cargar(a):

```
cont = 0
i = 0
j = 1

while(cont<10):
    num = int(input("ingrese un numero: "))
    if num % 2 == 0 and i<12:
        a.[i] = num
        i = i + 2 
        cont = cont + 1
    
    if num<0 and j<12:
        a[j] = num
        j = j+2
        cont = cont + 1
return
```

Espero que alguien pueda resolver esta duda

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas de mucho, si primeros creas la lista vacía entonces luego puedes ir añadiendo los elementos en la poscición que corresponda, para saber las posiciones puedes tener un contador para cada posción, es deccir uno para numeros pares y otro para impares, luego solo accedes a esa posición y cambiar el número.

```py
lista = [0 for _ in range(12)]

par, impar= 0,1
for i in range(12):
    num = int(input("ingrese un numero: "))
    if num%2:
        lista[par]= num
        par+=2
    else:
        lista[impar]= num
        impar+=2
print(lista)
```

Comment: La primera sentencia puede ser más Python así: lista = [0] *12

Comment: jaja claro, si deseas puedes editar la respuesta, aprobaré tu edición :D

Comment: Perdona, no era ninguna crítica a tu código, solamente trataba de aportar algo. Si lo prefieres borro todo.

Comment: noo, tu aporte esta bien. Solo decía que edites  la resuesta para que aporte quede como edición y seas recompenzado con +2 de reputación

Comment: @Christian solo veo un problema en la pregunta (no en la respuesta). Si los datos los va a introducir el usuario nada impide que los valores no sean 12 ceros (el cero sigue siendo par según Wikipedia). Faltan algunos datos en la pregunta. Si no se indica nada creo que sería mejor `i = [None] * 24`.

Comment: @TomyGijon lo que dices es cierto y eso es fallo del planteamiento del problema. Igual dejo esa implementación al OP. Si deseas puedes agregar esa observación a mi respuesta editandola :D

Answer (score 0):

El planteamiento sólo habla de "12 números", por lo que debe procesar correctamente cualquiera de las siguientes secuencias:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

Cuando la secuencia no trae cantidades iguales de pares e impares, usaremos `None` para rellenar la posición faltante.

**Método**

Teniendo la lista de valores, la recorremos en un ciclo formando dos listas: una de pares, otra de impares.

Si en algún momento ambas listas están pobladas, extraemos el primer elemento de cada una (el más antiguo) y los agregamos a la salida.

Al terminar cada ciclo, sólo una de las listas a lo más tendrá un valor en ella, pues tan pronto ambas tienen un valor, son sacadas a la salida.

Es posible que al terminar la entrada aún queden valores rezagados en "pares" o "impares", por lo que ejecutamos otro ciclo traspasándolos y rellenando con `None` cuando falte.

**Código**

Nótese que la solución no depende para nada del número de valores, por lo que funcionará con listas de cualquier tamaño. No necesito reservar espacio ni crear listas pre-pobladas.

```
def cargar(entrada: str) -> list:
    """
    Recibe una string con una lista de enteros separados por comas.

    Retorna una lista de enteros donde los valores pares van en indices
    pares y los impares en impares.
    """
    lista = entrada.split(',')

    pares = []
    impares = []
    salida = []

    for val in lista:
        valor = int(val)
        if valor % 2:
            impares.append(valor)
        else:
            pares.append(valor)

        if pares and impares:
            salida.append(pares.pop(0))
            salida.append(impares.pop(0))

    #   Sólo una de las listas podría tener valores
    for val in pares:
        salida.append(val)
        salida.append(None)

    for val in impares:
        salida.append(None)
        salida.append(val)

    return salida
```

**Demo**

Este programa prueba varios casos

```
tests = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "1,2,3,4,5",
    "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
    "1,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2",
    "1,1,1,3,3,5,5",
    "2, 4, 6, 8"
]

for test in tests:
    print(f"{test} -> {cargar(test)}")
```

con el siguiente resultado:

```
1 -> [None, 1]
2 -> [2, None]
1,2,3,4,5 -> [2, 1, 4, 3, None, 5]
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 -> [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9, 12, 11]
1,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2 -> [12, 1, 10, 11, 8, 9, 6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3]
1,1,1,3,3,5,5 -> [None, 1, None, 1, None, 1, None, 3, None, 3, None, 5, None, 5]
2, 4, 6, 8 -> [2, None, 4, None, 6, None, 8, None]
```